# System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded Visual studio 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Any idea how to fix this error on visual studio 2015 community

System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.

I made the changes in web.config file as advised in another question asked on stack overflow but it did not work

Comment: Could you show your web.config please.

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>                                                                                        And below                                                                      <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>

Comment: as advised here                                                                                                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

Comment: Are you adding that to root web.config?